# Telling TexStudio what bibtex command to use for a specific file

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

If I want to tell TexStudio what TeX program to use for a specific file, I just write this magic command at the top of the file:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -output=output %.tex
```

Is there a way to also tell it what bibtex command to use for a specific file?  I tried:

```
% !BibTeX program = bibtex output/%.aux
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Use `arara` package! Once you have set a TeXstudio button for it, it's much more convenient than the magic commands (and it works on any editor).

Comment: Have you tried `% !BIB program = bibtex output/%.aux`?

Comment: @Mico BIB also does not work: when I click Tools->Bibliography I get an error message showing that it does not run this command.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a bit more information about your typesetting setup. E.g., can you confirm the impression that the aux file "lives" in a subdirectory called `output`? Also, why do you specify an "extension" -- as  `%.aux`, no less?

Comment: @Mico I work on different papers with different co-authors who have different ways of orgainzing their files. Some of them put all the output files in the same folder as the tex file, while others like to put all the output files in a special "output" folder. For working with the others, I need to tell TexStudio to compile a specific file into the output folder, which I do with the  "TeX program" setting. But then, the "aux" file also ends up in the same output folder, so I have to tell bibtex to look for it there.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you any further as I don't use TeXstudio. (I use TeXworks...) You should definitely follow up on Carla's suggestion to set up and employ `arara`.

Comment: Following works for me, in Texstudio, which I got from https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/484 ```latex
% !BIB program = bibtex
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

```
% !BIB program = bibtex
```

as discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/484).

Simply add this "magic Tex comment" at the beginning of the file, and TexStudio will automatically call bibtex when you will try to compile the list of references.

You can find more information about them [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/wiki/Tips-And-Tricks#special-comments) and [there](https://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/).